# Non-linear external effect in Kalman filter

Tags: linear-systems, kalman-filters, non-linear

Let's say I have a Kalman filter with this simple state model:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k+1}\\ x^1_{k+1}\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \Delta t\\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k}\\ x^1_{k}\\ \end{pmatrix} + \mathbf{w_k}  \tag 1$$

where $x^1$ is the time derivative of $x^0$, and $\mathbf{w_k}$ is process noise.
This model describes properly the system as long as there is no significant external perturbation like temperature variation, because $x^1$ is an unknown function of temperature. Assuming as a first approximation that this function of temperature is linear I add the temperature derivative of $x^1$ to the model which become for a small temperature step $\Delta T = T_{k+1}-T_k$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k+1}\\ x^1_{k+1}\\ x^2_{k+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \Delta t & \Delta t \Delta T\\ 0 & 1 & \Delta T\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k}\\ x^1_{k}\\ x^2_{k} \end{pmatrix} + \mathbf{w_k} \tag 2 $$

This linear approximation works well in estimating $x^2$ as long as a small temperature range is covered but is not consistent when the full temperature range is taken into account because the non-linearity of $x^1(T)$ comes in. **How can I include a non-linear temperature behavior in the model ?**

An idea I have is to decompose the non-linear temperature behavior in piecewise linear temperature segments, adding as much variables to the state vector as there are linear behavior segments, with something like

$$\begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k+1}\\ x^1_{k+1}\\ x^2_{k+1} \\ ... \\ x^n_{k+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \Delta t & \Delta t \Delta T_{x^2} & ... & \Delta t \Delta T_{x^n}\\ 0 & 1 & \Delta T_{x^2} & ... & \Delta T_{x^n}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 &... & 1 \\ ... & ...& ... &...&... \\ 0 &0 &0&... &1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^0_{k}\\ x^1_{k}\\ x^2_{k} \\ ... \\ x^n_k \end{pmatrix} + \mathbf{w_k} \tag 3 $$

where  $ \Delta T_{x^i} = \Delta T $ if $ T_i < T <T_{i+1}$, or else 0.

Is this approach OK ? is there a more standard way to do this ?

I've read about extended Kalman filters (EKF) but it seems to me that EKF is appropriate for non-linear system dynamics, but here I consider my system still has linear time-dynamics but the non-linearity comes from an "external" effect so I don't know how I would apply the EKF approach to this particular case.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing that your model in (2) is representative.  It says that $x^1$ has a temperature-dependent drift that goes on _forever_, depending on some unknown state $x^2$.  Is this _really_ what you believe is going on?  Can you _edit your question_ to give _a narrative in plain language_ what you believe the temperature effect is?  I.e., "$x^1$ drifts with temperature in some nonlinear fashion" -- then rather than trying to give your guess at the way it _should_ be modeled, give your best guess in math at what is _actually going on_.

Comment: Well $\Delta T = T_{k+1} - T_k$ in (2) is the temperature variation since the last filter call, and $x^1(T)$  is a non-linear function of temperature. The linear approximation in (2) actually works well in estimating $x^2$ as long as small temperature changes are concerned. When the full temperature range is covered however this does not work because the non-linearity of  $x^1(T)$ comes in. I hope this is clearer

Comment: This is Stackexchange, which is different from other fora.  Stackexchange wants the **question itself** to be complete, without essential bits buried in the comments.  Could you please **edit your question** so that it is complete, rather than leaving essential bits in the comments?

Comment: Added some minor edits. The more general question (independently of this specific model given as an example) could have been "how do you handle external non-linear perturbations on top of a linear model?" The path I'm trying to follow here is to add state variables for piecewise linear estimation but I actually don't know if this is good approach.